# Show that a set of vectors of a vector space is a basis and find coordinates of a vector with respect to different bases

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $B_1=\{b_1,b_2,b_3\}$ is a basis of real vector space $V$. Show that a set of vectors $B_2=\{c_1,c_2,c_3\}$,such that $c_1=b_1+2b_2+3b_3,c_2=b_1+3b_2+2b_3,c_3=2b_1+3b_2+b_3$ is also a basis of the same vector space $V$. Find coordinates of vector $v=10b_1+15b_2+14b_3$ over basis $B_2$.

What is the procedure for finding coordinates of vector $v=10b_1+15b_2+14b_3$ over basis $B_2$?

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Just take $\ a,b,c\in{R}$ and solve a system of equations from $\ v=ac_1+bc_2+cc_3$

Comment: Could you expand your answer?

Comment: $\ 10b_1+15b_2+14b_3=(a+b+2c)b_1+(2a+2b+3c)b_2+(3a+2b+c)b_3 => 
a+b+2c=10,
2a+2b+3c=15,
3a+2b+c=14
$

Comment: For showing that a set of vectors $B_2$ is also a basis of the same vector space $V$, we must show that real number triplet $(x_1,x_2,x_3)$ is equal to $(0,0,0)$, right? From $x_1b_1+x_2b_2+x_3b_3=x_1c_1+x_2c_2+x_3c_3$ we get the system $x_2+2x_3=0,2x_1+2x_2+3x_3=0,3x_1+2x_2=0$ that gives $x_1=x_2=x_3=0$. If $x_1\neq 0$ or $x_2\neq 0$ or $x_3\neq 0$, the statement wouldn't be true, right?

Comment: You can't write this $\ x_1b_1+x_2b_2+x_3b_3=x_1c_1+x_2c_2+x_3c_3$ because in general coordinates of vectors aren't same for all basis.

Comment: I have described the first half of the problem. Is it correct?

Comment: To show that they are the two basis of the same vector space you only need to see if basis vector of one basis could be represented as linear combination of vectors from the other basis.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/57612/discussion-between-ctsnake-and-user300046).